# Why is GNU Radio "stuttering" with this flow graph?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I have a GNU Radio Companion flow graph, where I have the following connections:

- 440Hz cosine wave
- throttle block
- audio sink

[image: Flow Graph Screenshot]

All of the above blocks use the same sample rate (48KHz).

When I execute this flow graph, I don't get a continuous note, the way I expected. Instead, it pulses on and off, several times per second. Why is this?

How can I make it output a continuous 440Hz tone?

Removing the Throttle block makes it stop cutting in and out, but it sounds even worse when I do this.

I have tried this setup, with and without the Throttle block, at all common sample rates for sound cards.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring it out. I had to do three things:

- remove the Throttle block
- enable the "OK to Block" option in the audio sink
- ensure the amplitude of the sine wave is less than 1

Comment: indeed; GNU Radio Companion will even tell you about not using hardware blocks with a Throttle block in the same flow graph